# Does throwing an HttpsError() in a Firebase Callable Function cause the instance to be thrown away (and therefore cause a cold-start)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

In Google [Cloud Functions documentation about error reporting](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/error-reporting), it says "...that some types of uncaught exceptions (such as those thrown asynchronously) will cause a cold start to occur upon a future function invocation. This increases the amount of time your function will take to run."

Whereas in [Firebase Documentation about handling errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors), it says we should "return errors from a callable by throwing (or returning a Promise rejected with) an instance of functions.https.HttpsError ... to ensure the client gets useful error details":

```js
if (!(typeof text === 'string') || text.length === 0) {
  // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with one arguments "text" containing the message text to add.');
}
```

So to me this sounds like `HttpsError` is treated somehow specially compared to other thrown `Error`s.

**My question is:** Does throwing an `HttpsError` in a Callable Cloud Function as shown above cause the function to *fail* and therefore cause a **cold-start** for subsequent invocations?

If that would be the case, throwing `HttpsError`s would make no sense for such "expected" errors like missing arguments as in these cases, the Function instance could and should indeed be reused for performance reasons.

So if that's the case, it would be better to just return something like:

```js
return {
  error: true,
  error_code: 'invalid_argument',
}
```

and handle this on the client instead of the `HttpsError`.

Or would the correct solution to *return an error to the client* without causing the function to cause a cold start be to return a rejected Promise instead of throwing?

```js
if (!(typeof text === 'string') || text.length === 0) {
  // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
  return Promise.reject(new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with one arguments "text" containing the message text to add.'));
}
```

According to the docs, it does not sound like there's a difference between `throw new HttpsError(...)` and `return Promise.reject(new HttpsError(...))` but maybe I misread it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Firebase Callable Cloud Functions, by [sending back a result](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result) or by [throwing an instance of `functions.https.HttpsError`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) you actually indicate to the Cloud Function platform that your function has reached its terminating condition or state and that the platform **can** shut down the Cloud Function instance running your function.

What's important to note is that we use **can**: the platform may shut down the instance immediately or may not and let it up for some time, being idle. This is out of your control.

**Result:** If the next invocation of your Cloud Function occurs when the instance is still up this instance will be re-used and there will be no cold-start (the same would occur if another instance of the same Cloud Function is idle and still up). If, on the opposite, the instance was shut down when the next invocation occurs (and there is no other instance of the same Cloud Function idle and up), the platform will spin-up a new instance and there will be a cold start.

In other words, the Cloud Function platform will "look" if there is an instance of this particular Function that is up **and** idle. If yes, it will use it, if no it will spin-up a new instance.

**Conclusion**, in your case, on how to return an error like "missing arguments": You can either return an object like you do in your question (or return a Promise that resolves with this object if the Function implements some asynchronous operations) or throw an instance of `functions.https.HttpsError`. It will not make any difference in terms of cold start, see the comment of @samthecodingman below.

---

Note the following about the first sentence of this anwser:

"Sending back a result" means:

- Returning a JavaScript Object if there is no asynchronous operation in your Cloud Function (see the example in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result) for the result of an addition operation), or;
- Returning a promise after an asynchronous operation.

"Throwing an instance of `functions.https.HttpsError`" means:

- Doing `throw new functions.https.HttpsError(...)`, or;
- Returning a Promise rejected with an instance of `functions.https.HttpsError`.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that errors thrown in the callable function handler are contained within a Promise chain and that's also why they won't terminate the instance (in contrast to errors thrown in traditional HTTPS Request handlers which are just express handlers)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but I'm still not 100% sure about one central aspect by your answer. I'm aware of the general behavior that functions can be kept idle or also shut down at any time. Just considering the *function will be kept idle* state here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#error_reporting says "In languages that use exception handling, do not throw uncaught exceptions, because they force cold starts in future invocations.". So to be sure: Neither `throw new HttpsError(...)` nor `return Promise.reject(new HttpsError(...))` count as uncaught exception?

Comment: Hello @sceee, see the comment from samthecodingman